# GreenSock fade-in

Tags: javascript, html, gsap

Can't figure out whats wrong with this code? Below is HTML and GSAP JS script that loads after jquery and tweenmax/lite is loaded.

```
<div id="sidemenu" class="sidemenu">
<a href="#registerhere"><strong>register here</strong></a>
<hr />
<a href="#whatisincludedinthefee"><strong>what is included in the fee</strong></a>
<hr />
<a href="#onedayattendance"><strong>one-day attendance</strong></a>
<hr />
<a href="#accompanyingpersons"><strong>accompanying persons</strong></a>
</div>
<script>
defer(function () {
});
var $sidemenu = $('#sidemenu');
TweenLite.from($sidemenu, 5, {opacity: 0, ease: Power4.easeIn});
</script>
```

CSS

```
.sidemenu {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1090px) {
    .sidemenu {
        display: none !important;
}}
```